# MS-Access: Using ListBox selections from one form to filter results in another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Here is my problem:

I am working with MS-Access 2010. I have a form with a listbox reserved for employee names and employee IDs with 2 command buttons below. One button displays all of my employees. The other opens a modal form with filter criteria. In this model form i have another listbox with different HR categories (with multi-select enabled).

What I am attempting to do is: open my modal form, select one or more of these HR categories in my listbox, click a command button that then closes the modal form and updates the employee listbox based on the certain criteria i have selected.

Thanks in advance for help with this. This is driving me a little nuts :-)

Here is my updated code below.

```vb
Private Sub cmd_ExecuteEmpFilter_Click()
    Dim varItem As String
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim strSql As String

    'Building the criteria string from selected items in the list box
    varItem = ""
    For Each i In Me!lst_HRFilter.ItemsSelected
        If varItem <> "" Then
            varItem = varItem & " , "
        End If
        varItem = varItem & Me!lst_HRFilter.ItemData(i) & ""
    Next i

    'Filter the form using selected items inside the list box
    txt_HRCat = varItem

    strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT q.LastName, q.FirstName, q.EmployeeID " & _
    "FROM qry_MasterEmployeeFilter As q " & _
    "WHERE q.HomeTeamID=" & Me.txt_TeamID2 & _
    "AND q.ReportingGroupID IN (" & varItem & ") " & _
    "ORDER BY q.[LastName], q.[FirstName], q.[EmployeeID];"

Debug.Print strSql

Forms!frm_Employee_Updater.lst_AllEmps.RowSource = strSql

DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_EmployeeFilter", acSaveYes

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Why is it not working? Have you tried to set a breakpoint in the code and to look if the query you are building looks how you are expecting? Try to put the query in an empty query in SQL-view and try to execute it. May be you will see clearer then.

Comment: What is `qry_MasterEmployeeFilter.dbo_T_ReportingGroup.ReportingGroupID` ?

Comment: When I click the command button, my modal form closes but my employee list is not populated at all. I tried your suggestion of using the empty SQL view query and got the following error:  "This expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements"

Comment: @HansUp - That field is my HR CategoryID in my main Employee query. This query has several joins to various tables including the ReportingGroup table where my HR IDs are contained.

Comment: Removing the space before **AND** removed the roadblock behind the TeamID. Looking at the Immediate window, the TeamID is registering correctly but ReportingGroupID selection is still not picking up. **...WHERE q.HomeTeamID=3 AND q.ReportingGroupID IN () ORDER BY q.[LastName], q.[FirstName], q.[EmployeeID];**

Answer (score 0):

you need to requery the main form after you have changed its recordsource.

```
Forms!frm_Employee_Updater.lst_AllEmps.Requery
```